# Flurry Analytics Integration Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, flurry, flurry-analytics

After I successfully integrated flurry SDK into the library by using this code in my build.gradle file.

`compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.2.0'`

I created java Class to integrate my API Key into my code, but I faced this probleme and I have no clue what should I do to successfully integrate it

> -cannot resolve symbol FlurryAgent
>
> -cannot resolve symbol flurrylistener

[image: image of the error]

PS: I'm new to Flurry analytics and Android Studio

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: cannot resolve symbol flurrylistener + cannot resolve symbol FlurryAgent

Comment: Is flurryListener defined in the file somewhere?

Comment: I don't know, I just followed their 2 steps  flurry integration tuto and it gave me those 2 errors , also they said :If you're shipping an app, insert a call to FlurryAgent.build(Context, String) in your Application class, passing reference to your application Context and your project's API key , and I don't know if I did it correctly or not .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now just remove the withListener() line.
It's not necessary to initialize Flurry.
Once you have your integration working, you can go back and set it up if you want, I've found it only to be necessary if you need to send events before Flurry completes initialization.

Comment: Ok thank you, and what should I do with the FlurryAgent problem ?

Comment: Is it still giving an error?
If it is, them maybe the Builder() method was added in a later SDK version, trying using this in your build.gradle:
compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.4.2'

Answer (score 0):

Flurry is working to get this corrected. Joel Duggan is correct the listener is "only necessary if you need to send events before Flurry completes initialization."

We will be removing this line of code from the basic instructions:

.withListener(flurryListener)

And here is the correct syntax for those who need it:

`import com.flurry.android.FlurryAgentListener;`

....

FlurryAgent.Builder()
              .withLogEnabled(true)
              .withListener(new FlurryAgentListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSessionStarted() {
                      // Session handling code
                  }
              })
              .build(this, 'your_api_key');

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem, I have updated gradle and my problem is solved. Use latest gradle as follows,

//Flurry
 compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:7.0.0@aar'

for more reference [use this url](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/integrateflurry/android/)